# jQuery Sortable Table plugin for Rails 3 Recommendation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Inside a Rails 3 app, what jQuery plugin for sortable tables / grids would you recommend that satisfies these conditions:

- integrates well with Rails 3
- **sort** columns
- **resize** columns
- **filter** columns
- **show/hide** columns
- allows for **pagination**
- has a non viral licence: BSD, MIT are OK; (L)GPL is not
- is still under **active** development

I've been looking over the [jQuery Grid Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations), and also this article about [15 Great jQuery Plugins For Better Table Manipulation](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/) but there are many alternatives, and some even outdated.

I paid closer attention to [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), even [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/), as good candidates, but how is the dual licensing working? If it says

> Dual licensed under A **or** B licenses.

can I choose to respect only one of the 2 licences (the more permissive one)?

Comment: I thought LGPL wasn't viral, where GPL is.  Am I wrong?

Comment: LGPL isn't viral per se. But it's the kind of license IBM employees don't like to use because it complicates the internal approval process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for any other projects, but certainly with DataTables the software is published under GPLv2 OR a BSD 3 point license. You can pick which one you wish to use the software under (or both if you wanted, although that might be a little odd :-) ).